# Specifying a particular callback to be used in playbook

Tags: ansible

I have created different *playbooks* for different operations in [ansible](/questions/tagged/ansible).

And I have also created different *Callback Scripts* for different kinds of Playbooks (And packaged them with Ansible and installed).

The playbooks will be called from many different scripts/cron jobs.

Now, **is it possible to specify a particular `callback script` to be called for a particular playbook**? (Using a command line argument probably?)

What's happening right now is, all the Callback scripts are called for each playbook.

I cannot put the `callback script` relative to the location/folder of the playbook because it's already packaged inside the ansible package. Also, all the playbooks are in the same location too.

I am fine with modifying a bit of ansible source code to accommodate it too if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After going through the code of Ansible, I was able to solve it with the below...

In each `callback_plugin`, you can specify `self.disabled = True` and the callback wont be called at all...

Also, which calling a playbook, there's an option to parsing **extra arguments** as `key=value` pairs. It will be part of the playbook object as `extra_vars` field.

So I did something like this in my `callback_plugin`.

```
def playbook_on_start(self):
    callback_plugins = self.playbook.extra_vars.get('callback_plugin', '') // self.playbook is populated in your callback plugin by Ansible.
    if callback_plugins not in ['email_reporter', 'all']:
        self.disabled = True
```

And while calling the playbook, I can do something like,

```
ansible-playbook -e callback_plugin=email_reporter //Note -e is the argument prefix key for extra vars.
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are simply running a playbook via script you can do something like this

`ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK="json" ansible-playbook -i hosts play.yml`

You are setting the callback as an environment variable prior to ansible-playbook command running.

Answer (score 2):

If with *callback scripts* you mean [*callback plugins*](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#callbacks), you could decide in those plugins if any playbook should trigger some action.

In the `playbook_on_play_start` method you have the name of the play, which you could use to decide if further notifications should be processed or not.

`playbook_on_stats` then is called at the end of the playbook.

```
SHOULD_TRIGGER = false

class CallbackModule(object):

    def playbook_on_play_start(self, name):
        if name == "My Cool Play":
           SHOULD_TRIGGER = true

    def playbook_on_stats(self, stats):
        if SHOULD_TRIGGER == true:
           do something cool
```

Please note, `playbook_on_play_start` is called for every *play* in your playbook, so it might be called multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But I needed to specify callbacks based on playbook. Not based on each play... The same play could be called from 2 different playbooks and the callback should be called for 1 and not for other...

Comment: Just want to make sure you understand what a _play_ is, because a play can not "be called". A play is an entry in the playbook, each containing the hosts, tasks/roles and vars keys. Most playbooks do only contain one single play but you can have multiple plays. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-example The only situation where the above solution would not work, is, when you have plays with identical names in multiple playbooks.

Comment: that's right... I have multiple plays in each playbook... Moreover, I am also using `include` statements in my playbooks. Which means the same play will be included as part of many playbooks... So using this approach may cause me problems...